# Fetch data between two date in mysql

Tags: mysql

This is my query

```
WHERE id = 14 AND start_time BETWEEN '2019-10-24 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-12 23:59:59'  
ORDER BY created_date LIMIT  0 , 10
```

When I run this query then it returns me data of this data also. -> **2019-10-23T19:23:41.000Z**

**Issue:** When I pass the **2019-10-24** then why it gives me data of **2019-10-23** date?

**Note:** start_time has a data type -> `datetime` in db.

Comment: Your question is not complete. There is no query there, just `WHERE` clause. There is no source raw data and no real mysql output, but just your interpretation of those.
Another weird thing I see to start is you have `start_time` in `WHERE` but `created_date` in `OREDER BY`. Too many small questions which makes your question very confusing.

Comment: 2019-10-23T19:23:41.000Z? This does not look like MySQL formatted datetime. Who formatted it then? What is your server's timezone? What exactly was returned by MySQL is you issue the query directly in MySQL client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a issue by the way it's correct output.

Try this way

```
DATE_FORMAT(start_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") as start_time
```

Due to diffrent formate, It may confused you.

Comment: Yeah, It's my bad and I just fixed that in this way, Stil thanks for your reply...

Answer (score -1):

use less than or equal to '<=' or greater than or equal to '>=' operator instead of `BETWEEN`.

Use this condition in your query.

```
WHERE id = 14 AND DATE(start_time) >= DATE('2019-10-24 00:00:00') AND DATE(start_time) <= DATE('2019-12-12 23:59:59') ORDER BY created_date LIMIT  0 , 10
```

OR

```
WHERE id = 14 AND DATE(start_time) >= '2019-10-24' AND DATE(start_time) <= '2019-12-12') ORDER BY created_date LIMIT  0 , 10
```